# What's the right CAN bus settings for STM32F4-Disc for 250 kbit/s by using nanoFramework?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, bluepill, nanoframework, chibios

I'm trying to connect a [Blue Pill](https://stm32-base.org/boards/STM32F103C8T6-Blue-Pill.html) board (set up by STM32CubeMX) with STM32F4-Discovery (set up by [ChibiOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChibiOS/RT) and nanoFramework).

The Blue Pill has these parameters:

> - APB1 peripheral clock: 24 MHz
> - Prescaler (for Time Quantum): 6
> - *Time Quantum: 250.0 ns [as result]*
> - Time Quanta in Bit Segment 1: 13 Times
> - Time Quanta in Bit Segment 2: 2 Times
> - *Time for one Bit: 4000 ns [as result]*
> - *Baud Rate: 250 000 bit/s [as result]*
> - ReSynchronization Jump Width: 1 Time

Clock configuration in ChibiOS for Discovery board ([mcuconf.h](https://github.com/nanoframework/nf-Community-Targets/blob/main/ChibiOS/ST_STM32F4_DISCOVERY/nanoCLR/mcuconf.h)):

```
#define STM32_SW            STM32_SW_PLL
#define STM32_PLLSRC        STM32_PLLSRC_HSE
#define STM32_PLLM_VALUE    4
#define STM32_PLLN_VALUE    168
#define STM32_PLLP_VALUE    2
#define STM32_PLLQ_VALUE    7
#define STM32_HPRE          STM32_HPRE_DIV1
#define STM32_PPRE1         STM32_PPRE1_DIV8
```

My calculation for the APB1 peripheral clock of the Discovery board:

`Fext_osc / PLLM * PLLN / PLLP  / HPRE / PPRE1 = 8 000 000 / 4 * 168 / 2 / 1 / 8 = 21 MHz`

I tried to set up CAN of the Discovery board in code:

`var canSettings = new CanSettings(6, 11, 2, 1);`

where

> - Bus baud rate prescaler: 6
> - *[Time Quantum: 6 / 21+E6 = 285.71 ns as result]*
> - Phase segment 1: 11
> - Phase segment 2: 2
> - *[Time for one Bit: 285.71-E9 * (1 + 11 + 2) = 4000 ns as result]*
> - *[Baud Rate: 1 / 4-E6 = 250 000 bit/s as result]*
> - Synchronization jump width: 1

The connection doesn't work.

If I use settings from some code [sample](https://www.hackster.io/sjmn/nanoframework-can-demo-db8a2d) for unknown speed—*CanSettings(6, 8, 1, 0)*—it works, but it's 350 kbit/s (for a 21 MHz *APB1* clock).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation about [`CanSettings`](https://docs.nanoframework.net/api/nanoFramework.Device.Can.CanSettings.html#nanoFramework_Device_Can_CanSettings__ctor_System_Byte_System_Byte_System_Byte_System_Byte_). Make sure to pass those values to the constructor in the correct parameters.

I haven't validated if they are correct though. I suggest that you use one of STM calculators to make it easy.